# DMux.hdl failure when in=1, sel=0

Tags: debugging, hdl, hardware, nand2tetris

I'm writing the hdl code for a DMux based on the Nand2Tetris course.

```
CHIP DMux {
IN in, sel;
OUT a, b;

PARTS:
And(a = sel, b = in, out = b);
Not(in = sel, out = selNot);
And(a = in, b = selNot, out = a);   
}
```

For some reason, this code fails on the test script values of `in = 1 and sel = 0`. It evaluates `a` and `b` both to 0 in this case.

I have written out the gates multiple times, and I can't figure out why the result is not `a = 1 and b = 0`

Can someone explain to me what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling your Not implementation may have a problem.

Try replacing the Not with a Nand:

```
Nand(a=sel,b=sel,out=notSel);   // notSel = ! sel
```

If this works, then your Not.hdl is incorrect.

Also, on a style point, it's clearer if you define your intermediates before your final outputs (ie: put the Nand first), and be consistent in your input ordering (ie: a=in, b=sel or notSel, out = a or b). Helps reduce the chance you will misread something.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that anything is wrong with your code. It looks to be the same as mine, which works. Have you tested your other And and Not gates?

My code:

```
Not(in=sel, out=notsel);
And(a=notsel, b=in, out=a);
And(a=in, b=sel, out=b);
```